# XPath Combine Node Texts Based On Condition

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following HTML document:

```
<div>
  <span>Line 1</span>
  <p>
    <span class='inline'>This</span>
    text should 
    <span class='inline'>be in</span>
    one 
    <span class='inline'>line</span>
    <span class='inline'>all together</span>
  </p>
  <em>
    <span class='inline'>This</span>
    line
    <span class='inline'>too</span>
  </em>
  <a href="#">Line 4</a>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span class='inline'>This fourth</span>
      line
      <span class='inline'>too</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">//...</script>
  <b></b>
</div>
```

The text that should be extracted:

```
Line 1
This text should be in one line all together
This line too
Line 4
This fourth line too
```

At the moment I am using `//div//descendant::*[not(self::script)]/text()[string-length() > 0]` to extract the text.

That leads to the following result:

```
Line 1
This
text should
be in
one
line
all together
This
line
too
Line 4
This fourth
line
too
```

How can I combine the texts in case the class 'inline' is used? Or how can I use the parent node's text in case the class 'inline' has been spotted inside a child node?

Note that this is an example: **The p and em tag could vary!**

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps you're looking at the wrong point. What popped into my eyes was that you're looking for the text-content of any child of the *div* (here also the root) element - but for the script tag and if empty:

```
/div/*[name() != "script" and string-length(normalize-space())]
```

My xpath example also does space normalization. E.g. if `<b></b>` would be `<b>   </b>` or with some line-break it would qualify as empty, too.

Reading `DOMNode::$textContent` and normalizing spaces with it produces the following results:

```
string(6) "Line 1"
string(44) "This text should be in one line all together"
string(13) "This line too"
string(6) "Line 4"
string(20) "This fourth line too"
```

Here is a quick PHP example code [demonstrating this](https://eval.in/477176):

```
<?php

$buffer = <<<XML
<div>
  <span>Line 1</span>
  <p>
    <span class='inline'>This</span>
    text should
    <span class='inline'>be in</span>
    one
    <span class='inline'>line</span>
    <span class='inline'>all together</span>
  </p>
  <em>
    <span class='inline'>This</span>
    line
    <span class='inline'>too</span>
  </em>
  <a href="#">Line 4</a>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span class='inline'>This fourth</span>
      line
      <span class='inline'>too</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">//...</script>
  <b></b>
</div>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
$result = $xml->xpath('/div/*[name() != "script" and string-length(normalize-space())]');
foreach ($result as $node) {
    $text = dom_import_simplexml($node)->textContent;
    $text = preg_replace(['(\s+)u', '(^\s|\s$)u'], [' ', ''], $text);
    var_dump($text);
}
```